# Apply doit() function in SymPy only to the outer part of an expression

Tags: python, sympy

the `doit()` function in `sympy` goes ahead and evaluates expressions whenever possible. For instance:

```
from sympy import *
u = IndexedBase('u')
i = symbols('i')
test = Sum(u[i],(i,1,3))
test.doit()
```

Will return

[image]

Also:

```
from sympy import *
u,x = symbols('u, x')
test = Derivative(u,x)
test.doit()
```

Creates the symbolic differential and then evaluate it. The evaluation turns out to be zero in this case:

[image]

[image]

But what if I wanted a `Derivative` inside of a `Sum`? The `doit()` function goes a step too far:

```
from sympy import *
u = IndexedBase('u')
x = IndexedBase('x')
i = symbols('i')
test = Sum(Derivative(u[i],x[i]),(i,1,3))
test.doit()
```

This will return again zero. I would like to expand the sum but not actually evaluate the derivative. This should result in an expression as follows:

[image]

How can I get this as my output? Is there away to have the `doit()` command work only on the outer function (`Sum()`) but not the inner function (`Derivative()`)? Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out one way to do it.

Upon careful inspection of the `doit()` command arguments, it appears that setting option `deep = False` will prevent the evaluation from going too deep into the expression. Furthermore some indications show it is possible to control this more thoroughly. The command documentation shows:

> Evaluate objects that are not evaluate by default like limits,
>   integrals, sums and products. All objects of this kind will be
>   evaluated recursively, **unless some species were excluded via 'hints'
>   or unless the 'deep' hint was set to 'False'**.

For my part, I am very curious how the 'hints' can be harnessed. If someone can provide additional insight as to how the 'hints' work that would be great. Thanks.